# Why my White Bell Peachleaf Bellflower's leaves are curling up or leaning upwards?

Tags: flowers, plant-health, leaves, plant-care, perennials

I bought this plant on March 15, 2017 at RONA Garden Centre.
Yesterday when I planted it in this pot the leaves are all like natural, no curling sign/stem moving at that any point. But today on March 16, 2017 this morning I noticed this plant's got about 2 leaves that are halfway or sideway curling also some of these leaf stems are leaning not down like yesterday's but upwards, is this normal or not okay? Is it normal for this type of Bellflower to have curly leaves/stems leaning upwards or it might be a problem and how to solve it...
(Notice The One Middle Leaf That is Curled Up Halfways & Some Of Their Stems Are Leaning Upwards Today?)

> THE PLANT ON YESTERDAY
>   [image]
>   THE PLANT ON YESTERDAY
>   [image]
>
> THE PLANT ON TODAY
>   [image]
>   THE PLANT ON TODAY
>   [image]

Comment: where are you and what are your temperatures like overnight currently - have you had the plant outside all the time, or indoors since you bought it?

Comment: I am in Surrey, British Columbia, Canada. I have my plant indoors from Yesterday and Today since I bought it. I am not sure if it's the temperature problem because the weather is kind of more warmer right now here at my place, it just had a period of cloudy rain showers, maybe spring is coming?

Comment: Could you check the hidden part of the leaves?  Check carefully, for me it could be some small plant bug (aphids).

Comment: When you bought it, was it outdoors, or  under partial shelter like a roofed open space, or indoors?

Comment: When I bought it, it was under partial shelter but not fully roofed where there's some rain that can come down through, I think there's two greenhouse rooms, one is for the tropical plants that are inside, another is for the other plants like veggies, shrubs, trees, perennials, fruits, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Your Campanula persicifolia is an outdoor plant -it's a hardy herbaceous perennial, and it is not going to be at all happy indoors, so as you've had it indoors since you got it, you'll need to harden it off by placing outdoors for increasing periods of time over a week or so until it's out all night. If it was under partial shelter where you bought it, you should try to duplicate that situation as far as is possible until the weather warms more, even if its only standing it against the house wall in a sunny spot, which would give more shelter initially.